# How can I minimize this function in R?

Tags: r, function, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm attempting to write a formula that will determine a value of `a` that minimizes the function output `myfun` (i.e. `a-fptotal`). MWE:

```
c <- as.matrix(c(.25,.5,.25))
d <- as.matrix(c(10000,12500,15000))
e <- 700
f <- 1.1
tr <- .30

myfun <- function(a) {
   b <- max(a-e,0)
   df <- data.frame(u1=c(c*b*.40),u2=c(c*b*.60))
   df$year <- 1:nrow(df)
   df$factor <- 1/(f)^df$year
   df$d <- d
   df$t <- (df$d-df$u1-df$u2)*tr
   df$f <- df$d-df$t
   df$fp <- df$f*df$factor
   fptotal <- sum(df$fp)
   return(a-fptotal) # what is a good approach to minimize this?
}
```

I've tried things like this without any success:

```
o2 <- optimize(myfun, lower = 0, upper = 30000)
```

The correct answer should be around `28355`:

```
myfun(28355)  
## [1] -1.04151
```

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I got 30000. Basically, you have to change only this : `return(-(a-fptotal))`

Comment: @user227710, you just switched from minimizing to maximizing (which is also wrong, I think ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to minimize the *square* of `a-fptotal` ...

```
ff <- function(x) myfun(x)^2
> optimize(ff,lower=0,upper=30000)
$minimum
[1] 28356.39

$objective
[1] 1.323489e-23
```

Or find the root (i.e. where `myfun(x)==0`):

```
uniroot(myfun,interval=c(0,30000))
$root
[1] 28356.39

$f.root
[1] 1.482476e-08

$iter
[1] 4

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103517e-05
```

Comment: This is great, and the fast response is really appreciated. Thank you!